# Creating a new list based on checked boxes in list

Tags: java, android, search, checkboxlist

I'm creating an app where the user selects checkboxes and then is given the best option. I am having problems figuring out how to pass the data on to another activity, as well a prioritizing the objects (Buttons).

Right now the code sees which boxes are checked and creates a string buffer out of them.

```
StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
responseText.append("");

ArrayList<Items> stateList = dataAdapter.stateList;

for(int i=0;i<stateList.size();i++)
{
    Items state = stateList.get(i);
    if(state.isSelected())
    {
        responseText.append("\n" + state.getName());
    }
}
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
responseText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

What should I use to create a system in which the buttons are put in order by the accuracy of the tags ex : I check banana, ice-cream, sugar It shows Banana smoothie first because you checked all the variables required, it shows banana next because you only have 1 variable that is required to make it .

The variable that I want to pass it with must be able to be added by hand so:

```
Smoothie = banana,ice-cream,sugar
pie = banana, flour, egg.
```

I'm sorry, I'm new to java and I don't have knowledge in all the variables.

I hope I'm being clear.

Workflow image:

[image]

Comment: You need to clarify few things: 1. What do you mean "buttons are prioritized"? 2. What kind of data you want to pass to other activity and for what purpose?

Comment: the buttons are put in order by the accuracy of the tags ex : I check banana, ice-cream, sugar It shows Banana smoothie first because you checked all the variables required, it shows banana next because you only have 1 variable that is required to make it . ( I updated the info)

Comment: The variable that I want to pass it with must be able to be added by hand so:

Smoothie = banana,ice-cream,sugar
pie= banana, flour, egg

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating an array with selected values and then used the .contains("Banana") to get a true or false value. so it looks something like

```
if(recipesList.contains("banana")){

 // code to show recipes for everything that needs a banana-
}
```

I think for Prioritizing the list I will change the position variable in the new list by adding 1 int for each true statement.